# Open a new window and close that window after 5 sec

Tags: javascript

I have a function that should open an authentication window (IwAuthentication) and after 5 sec close that window and open a new one (IwUrl). I tried lot of code and I am able to complete all tasks but window.Close it doesn't work and my IwAuthentication still open. Any advices? My code below

Thanks!

```
var IwAuthentication = "http://etc";
var IwUrl = "http://etc");

function openwindowAuthentication() {
    var myWindow = window.open(IwAuthentication, "myWindow", "width=500, height=500");
}

window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.open(IwsUrl, myWindow, "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
    closewindowAuthentication();
}, 5000);

function closewindowAuthentication() {
    myWindow = window.close();   // Closes the new window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myWindow = window.open(IwAuthentication, "myWindow", "width=500, height=500");

setTimeout(function () {
    myWindow.close();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things

1. Declare the variable `myWindow` outside of the function
2. refer to `myWindow.close()` not `window.close()`

---

```
var IwAuthentication = "http://etc";
var IwUrl = "http://etc");
var myWindow = null;

function openwindowAuthentication() {
    myWindow = window.open(IwAuthentication, "myWindow", "width=500, height=500");}

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.open(IwsUrl, myWindow1, "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
        closewindowAuthentication();
    }, 5000);

function closewindowAuthentication() {
     myWindow.close();   // Closes the new window
}
```